# Which is better, SD or SE in line charts?

Tags: data-visualization, standard-deviation, standard-error

Among the literature, some line charts use mean/SE but others use mean/SD. Which is correct or better?

Comment: It depends on whether you are trying to indicate to the devil the variation in values or uncertainty in the estimate of the mean

Comment: Neither is better as long as you are clear as to what you have done.

Comment: Related questions of interest, [Follow up: In a mixed within-between ANOVA plot estimated SEs or actual SEs?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2067/1036), and [Analyze and visualize participants response towards particular condition](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/22731/1036).

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://jcb.rupress.org/content/177/1/7.full) is a popular paper (it is the second most popular paper on Mendeley) on the subject of error bars and SD vs. SE, aimed at biologists - so it is pretty simple :) .